# Change Chrome's font for a specific website?

Tags: google-chrome, fonts

Is it possible to change the font in Chrome for a specific website?
For example, I want to read Wikipedia with Arial 16, but for all other websites I want to use a default font Segoe UI 14pt.
I looked a the settings, but I couldn't find an option to set the font for a specific website.
Thanks.

Comment: [TamperMonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo?hl=en) will probably do what you want.

Comment: Natively in Chrome you can ofcourse modify the css of the webpage. Needless to say this formatting will be lost when reloading - but for one-time use it can be easy. Otherwise one of the already mentioned extensions will serve you well.

Comment: For reference, this [was natively possible prior to Chrome 33](https://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome?revision=234007&view=revision), but that feature has been removed.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Update May 2020: Looks like this extension has been removed. You can use [Custom Font Changer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/custom-font-changer/dhffbhalonlcppiahghbjodoaklbbmda?hl=en-GB) instead!

---

AFAIK, Chrome does not allow you to do this *by default*, but you can use this helpful extension called [Font Changer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/font-changer-with-google/jgjhhoglgjdklldfgoffdiaceffijeke?hl=en) to change the font for any website.

It's really easy to use - just click the icon next to the address bar and change the size, font, style, or weight. You can also choose your own font (eg. a `.ttf` TrueType Font file) and use that.

[image]

BTW I'm not affiliated with it.

Comment: Using the dev tools you can do this, temporarily, with completely stock Chrome. But that change is reset on every page load. For something permanent the above solution is good. You can take it even deeper with another extension called Stylish - though that requires knowledge of CSS.

Comment: The extension's URL has changed.

Comment: @Michaël updated the post with a different one!

Comment: That new page is also gone, it seems.

Comment: Seems like it :( You could try https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/font-changer/obgkjikcnonokgaiablbenkgjcdbknna?hl=en but I haven't tried it myself! @Deancue

Comment: The two links are neither available now.

Answer (score 8):

You can also use an extension call `Stylebot`([link](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylebot/oiaejidbmkiecgbjeifoejpgmdaleoha?hl=en)) on Chrome. It's not just limited to font changing but allow you to inject custom css to it.

Comment: This is a better product than Font Changer, imo, because you can right-click and change specific elements instead of the whole page.

Comment: Thanks a lot for suggesting this, I find it quite helpful!